# What to do when Memgraph stops working without any info?

Tags: memgraphdb

Sometimes the Docker container where Memgraph is running just stops working or says that the process was aborted with exit code 137. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the **Memgraph logs**, where you'll probably find the reason why the process was aborted.

Since you said that you're using Memgraph with Docker, there are two options:

1. If you run Memgraph with Docker **using the volume for logs**, that is with
   `-v mg_log:/var/log/memgraph`, then `mg_log` folder usually can be found at `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\` (Windows) or `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` (Linux and macOS).
2. If you run Memgraph **without using the volume for logs**, then you need to enter the Docker container. In order to do that, first you have to find out the container ID by running `docker ps`. Then you have to copy the container ID and run `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`. For example, if container ID is `83d76fe4df5a`, then you run `docker exec -it 83d76fe4df5a bash`. Next, you need find the folder where logs are located. You can do that by running `cd /var/log/memgraph`. To read the logs, run `cat <memgraph_date>.log`, that is, if you have log file `memgraph_2022-03-02.log` located inside the log folder, then run `cat memgraph_2022-03-02.log`.

Hopefully, when you read the logs, you'll be able to fix your problem.